# Find properties of images in WP

Tags: image, wordpress, post

When inserting an image via media uploader into a wordpress Post, is there a way to know all the properties of that image the same way wp has `global $post` which shows all properties of the post it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite what you mean but a WP attachment (be it an image or any other type of uploaded media) is treated as a post.  Therefore you can run `get_posts` to get an array of attachment objects that match your criteria.  Then use a `foreach` loop to display whatever data you need from these objects e.g.:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
         the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
    }
}
```

You can also use any other parameters of the WP_Query class to build your query within get_posts and narrow down the attachements that you're after - you will need to specify attachement as the post type though

Resources you want to check out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link (also look at the related functions at the bottom)

Comment: Running `get_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'attachment'))` did the trick. I could see all the image properties of all the attachments now. Will a simple conditional I can easily narrow it down to display only attachments from a specific post.

Comment: Found something more direct: `get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID, 'post_type'=>'attachment'))`.